# Can I use a double て form?

Tags: grammar

If I said "ポーランドに住んでいて、学生です。" would that be correct? I'm a beginner and I'm not sure if "sunde ite" sounds right to me

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can. It's perfectly fine to use two te-forms like this. They serve different purposes.

In this specific case, it's actually a little more natural to say ポーランドに住んでいる学生です (using a relative clause) or ポーランドの学生です, but you'll acquire such a sense as you learn.

Answer (score 4):

I don’t think you should see it as a "double て-form."

A verb in its て-form followed by certain other (helper) verbs such as います, あります, 行きます, 来ます, etc. is a common structure in Japanese. When you use this in various grammatical functions, you change the form of the second verb. The second て-form here is just one such inflection.

It’s probably more natural to say 学生で、ポーランドに住んでいます to put your status first, though.